# How to get the same scaling on two monitors

Tags: display-resolution

Could someone please help me with my scaling problem? I've tried everything but I cannot get it right, I just want my things to be same size on both monitors (3840x2160 and 2560x1440).

Picture of my current situation (I cannot use Chromium on my main monitor at the moment):

[image]

My xrandr:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed, here's how:

1. I enabled HiDPI mode on chromium.
2. went to settings->Display->Scaling and set everything 2 times larger on my screen that was scuffed.
3. $ xrandr --output DP-4 --scale 2.5x2.5